# IllegalArgumentException: Navigation action/destination packagename/action_xxx cannot be found from the current destination

Tags: java, android, navigationcontroller

I am having an issue with the Android Navigation Architecture component when I try to navigate from one Fragment to another within a viewpager, I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation action/destination 
com.gigaweb.mysales:id/action_mainFragment_to_addTransactionFragment cannot be found from the current 
destination Destination(com.gigaweb.mysales:id/pagerFragment) label=fragment_pager class=com.gigaweb.mysales.PagerFragment
```

I have a viewpager which I use to navigate between two Fragments and it works just fine. the problem is that I have a button within one of the fragments, the button is also used to navigate to another Fragment using navcontroller, and when the button is clicked the app crashes and I get the error above.

[image: Below is the screenshot of the error]

**Update** This is the navGraph

As you can see the SignIn Fragment is the start Destination and there is an action liking it to the pagerFragment which serves as the host for the ViewPager

the way I want the app to work is:

1. When the app launches The signIn Fragment is shown ..... working
2. Navigate to PagerFragment when SignIn Button is clicked ..... working
3. Navigate between MainFragment and AdminFragment by swiping left or right ..... working
4. Navigate to AddTransactionFragment whin the FAB Button is clicked ..... **NOT WORKING!!** as the button is clicked the app crashes.

**Update** Here is the XML code for the Navigation Graph

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
app:startDestination="@id/signInFragment">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/signInFragment"
    android:name="com.gigaweb.mysales.SignInFragment"
    android:label="fragment_sign_in"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_sign_in" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_signInFragment_to_pagerFragment"
        app:destination="@id/pagerFragment" />
</fragment>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/addTransactionFragment"
    android:name="com.gigaweb.mysales.AddTransactionFragment"
    android:label="AddTransactionFragment" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_addTransactionFragment_to_mainFragment"
        app:destination="@id/mainFragment" />
</fragment>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
    android:name="com.gigaweb.mysales.MainFragment"
    android:label="MainFragment" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_mainFragment_to_addTransactionFragment"
        app:destination="@id/addTransactionFragment" />
</fragment>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/adminFragment"
    android:name="com.gigaweb.mysales.AdminFragment"
    android:label="AdminFragment" />
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/pagerFragment"
    android:name="com.gigaweb.mysales.PagerFragment"
    android:label="fragment_pager"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_pager" />
</navigation>
```

[image]

Comment: So is there an `<action>` element called `action_mainFragment_to_addTransactionFragment` in the `<fragment android:id="@+id/pagerFragment"` destination? Because that's the destination you're on when that `onClick` fires. Please show your navigation graph and how those destinations relate to your ViewPager.

Comment: @ianhanniballake yes the above action you mention is the action triggered by the button click. I added the screenshot of the navigation graph in my update

Comment: Please include the actual Navigation XML file in your question, not just a screenshot of the design surface.

Comment: @ianhanniballake ok

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you do not `navigate()` to `MainFragment` and `AdminFragment`, you will remain on the last destination you navigated to: `PagerFragment`, that is the expected behavior. The NavController knows nothing about child fragments such as fragments within a ViewPager of `PagerFragment` and therefore you were never on `MainFragment` as a destination.

If you never `navigate()` to `MainFragment` or `AdminFragment` and they are only viewable as part of your ViewPager, then `MainFragment` and `AdminFragment` should not **be** in your graph. Any actions from fragments within `PagerFragment`'s ViewPager should be actions on `PagerFragment` directly (the destination you're actually on).

Comment: I get it. but is there any way I can navigate between child fragments of a ViewPager?

Comment: ViewPager certainly lets you call `setCurrentItem(indexOfThePageYouWantToGoTo)`, but that has nothing to do with the Navigation Component. What does that have to do with navigating to your `AddTransactionFragment`?

Comment: The problem is that I want the navigation to occur on button click and 
    AddTransactionFragment is not a child to the ViewPager

Comment: It is perfectly fine to navigate to `AddTransactionFragment` from any child fragment of the ViewPager as long as the action you're triggering is on your `PagerFragment` - the destination you're actually on.

Answer (score 0):

For my case, I resolve the problem by replacing -

```
 <action
        android:id="@+id/action_mainFragment_to_addTransactionFragment"
        app:destination="@id/addTransactionFragment" />
```

with

```
 <action
            android:id="@+id/action_mainFragment_to_addTransactionFragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" /* If true then also remove the destination from stack while popup */
            app:popUpTo="@id/mainFragment"  /*The fragment where to land again from destination*/
            app:destination="@id/addTransactionFragment" />
```

Answer (score 0):

For my case, it turns out it caused by calling `dismissAllowingStateLoss();` after navigating to new destination.